# How can I use mousemove event in c#

Tags: c#

The question is this:

when the mouse cursor moved on the button some thing should be happen but I don't know what exactly have to write

Comment: Your question should be more specific; what kind of application is this; what you have tried so far etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create eventHandler like this :

```
myButton.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(doSomething);
```

Where `myButton` is the button from which you want to trigger the event when mouse moves over it. and `doSomething()` is the method defined as like the following:

```
public void doSomething(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // do what ever you want
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When you select the button in the VS-designer you will have access to the properties and events (lightning Icon in the property window). [image]

In the events-listing are all events that the button can fire. May be for your purpose the events: ´MouseEnter´ and ´MouseLeave´ would be a good choice. Just double click the event and Visual Studio will generate the appropriate method. Like this:

```
private void button1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // my code
     this.button1.BackColor = Color.Red;
}

private void button1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // my code
     this.button1.BackColor = Color.Green;
}
```

In my example I just change the backcolour of the button when the mouse is on the button and change it again when it leaves the button.
Practically you could run any code inside the generated method.